# UIRefreshControl hidden by a customview: how to proceed?

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-view, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

I've a UIViewController which contain an UITableView with a UIRefreshControl as a subview of this tableview.
When there is at least one element in the tableview, everything is fine. I can pull-to-refresh without issue.

However, I created recently a new custom view which mean to be displayed above the tableview when there is no element in it. It look like this:
[image]

The issue is: when there is this "no element" custom view displayed, my UIRefreshControl does not work anymore. It's a normal behavior: there is a view above my tableview so gesture controls are not working on the tableview.
So my question is: how can I manage my view so I will be able to pull-to-refresh even if there are this "no element" custom view above my tableview?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I did not thougth enought about this question...
I just simply need to add this customview as a subview of my tableview.

Answer (score 1):

First you disable the user interaction of customView. Then may be it will be help you to resolve your problem.